# Irreducible elements of the ring of all numbers of the form $2^ab,$ where $a$ and $b$ are integers

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

As the title explains, I'm trying to solve a question which asks me to determine which are the irreducible elements of the ring of numbers of the form $2^ab,$ where $a$ and $b$ are integers (with the usual addition and multiplication).

I have no idea to do this, so I'd really appreciate any help you could give.

Comment: Why are you interested in this question?

Comment: The first thing to determine is: what are the [units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_(ring_theory)) in this ring?

Answer (score 2):

In a totally elementary fashion, note first that the integer prime $2$ has become a unit in this ring $R$.

Now show that every element of $R$, which is not zero nor a unit, can be written, up to unit factors, as the product of odd integer primes. (Just note that in the representation $2^{a} b$, you may take $b$ to be odd.)

And then, show that the odd integer primes remain prime in $R$. (Let $p$ be such a prime, and suppose it divides $2^{a_{1}} b_{1} \cdot 2^{a_{2}} b_{2}$ in $R$ (thus $a_{i}, b_{i}$ are integers). Then it divides $2^{a} b_{1} b_{2}$ in $\mathbb{Z}$ for some $a \ge 0$, and thus it  divides either $b_{1}$ or $b_{2}$.)

Answer (score 1):

This is the localisation of $\mathbb Z$ at two. Thus, it is also a UFD. Hence, the irreducible elements are precisely the primes, and by the correspondence theorem, these are the primes $p \neq 2$ multiplied by some power of $2$.

Comment: What is "the correspondence theorem" precisely? (There is quite a number, and I don't remember one for localizations.)

Answer (score 1):

We write $b$ into the form $b = 2^ic$, while c is an odd integer. And $2^ab=2^a(2^ic)$

If $c=1$,  $2^ab=2^a2^i$ which is a unit

If $c$ is a composite number, for example $c=xy$, then $2^ab=x2^a*y2^i$, which is reducible

Only if $c$ is an odd prime, $2^ab$ is irreducible

In conclusion, the irreducible elements can be written in the form  $2^ab$, while $b = 2^i*p$

($p$ is an odd prime)